# angularjs ng-show with promise expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-show` with an expression that resolves to a *promise* that resolves to a boolean.  When I do this I get the 10 digest iterations overflow.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/XibYM0kCnXhKjNUeTsp3?p=preview

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-show="returnsABoolean()">non promise</p>
    <p ng-show="returnsAPromiseThatResolvesToABoolean()">promise</p>
  </body>
```

Ctrl:

```
  $scope.returnsABoolean = ()->
    true

  $scope.returnsAPromiseThatResolvesToABoolean = ()->
    $q.when(false)
```

I know that `{{somePromise}}` will resolve, but `{{returnsAPromiseThatResolvesToABoolean()}}` seems to cause the same issue.

Any ideas?  I'd expect this to work..

Answer (score 7):

AngularJS resolves the promise for template binding automatically. However, you should use the promise in `ng-init` to prevent the digest cycle from returning a new promise every tick.

```
<p ng-init="v=returnsAPromiseThatResolvesToABoolean()" ng-show="v">promise</p>
```

Comment: According to the Angular 1.3 docs, this wouldn't be an appropriate use of ng-init: `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.`, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Answer (score 5):

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NvjP5qHafhyIWXXotBej?p=preview

This works as I think you intended it to. `$q.when()` returns a promise object, so `ng-show` is not getting a boolean value; it's getting a promise object.

Updated template:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-show="returnsABoolean()">non promise</p>
    <p ng-show="returnsAPromiseThatResolvesToABoolean">promise</p>
  </body>
```

Updated Ctrl:

```
  $scope.returnsABoolean = ()->
    true

  promise = $q.when(false)
  promise.then((val) ->
    $scope.returnsAPromiseThatResolvesToABoolean = val)
```

Comment: Can you provide a Plunkr in JavaScript?

Comment: Less "returnsAPromiseThatResolvesToABoolean" and more "willAtSomePointBeABooleanPropertySetToTheResolvedValueOfAPromiseInAThenCallback" now.

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the sources [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L443) you 'll see that the promise is resolved in `nextTick`, so the `$scope` only changes the next time angular makes a `$digest` cycle. But your function returns a new promise on every `$digest` cycle, never actually getting the resolved value of the previous promise.

It's an old problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323323/promise-callback-not-called-in-angular-js) also.

You can overcome this issue by keeping a "persistent" reference to your promise outside the function as I did [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZEnPrTnYjDNtZCInDK2?p=preview).