# AngularJS promise - 'then' not called within modal

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I think that I am missing something obvious but I can't quite figure this out. I am executing a promise in a controller that backs a modal dialog.

Here is the code;

```
$scope.elevate = ->
  $auth.authenticate('github', { auth_level: 'elevated' }).then((response) ->
    $scope.user.auth_level = 'elevated'
    return
  ).catch (response) ->
    alert response
    return

  return
```

The `elevate` function is called when the user clicks a button on the modal dialog. The code executes fine (no errors) but the promise is never resolved. The 'then' function is never called.

I read elsewhere that a call to `$rootScope.$digest` would do the trick but trying that just gives a "$apply already in progress" error.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: you tried to use a timeout?

Comment: I did. Interestingly, this just worked in Chrome (I was originally testing in Safari). So I am going to log this up to a browser issue for now (although I find that hard to believe).

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323323/promise-callback-not-called-in-angular-js

Comment: So, what's `$auth.auuthenticate`?

Comment: The `$auth` service is the one resolving the promise. If your `.then` is not called, or intermittently called then it an issue resolving the promise, not chaining it.

Comment: Did `$auth.auuthenticate` return a promise?

Comment: It did, yes. Also @dpaul1994 - thanks for the link. I'll take a look. I've got a feeling that this has something to do with Safari though...